# Test if join has been called

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread

Is it legal to call the joinable() function inside a thread's while loop to test if there was a join request on the thread or are there any side effects I do not consider at the moment?

Comment: " to test if there was a join request on the thread " - that's not what joinable() tells you.

Comment: There is no way in the standard for a thread to check and see if `join` has been called on it.  If you want to terminate the thread you a `condition_variable` or `atomic<bool>`.

Comment: Thank you. Using condition_variable and atomic<bool> works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it legal to call the `joinable()` function inside a thread's while loop to test if there was a join request on the thread or are there any side effects I do not consider at the moment?

This will probably cause a data race (therefore undefined behaviour) unless you use some kind of manual synchronization.

`std::thread::join()` is a non-const member function, therefore any call to it that is potentially concurrent with any other call to a member function of the same object will *conflict*, and cause a data race.

So if one thread calls `std::thread::join()` and another thread concurrently calls `std::thread::joinable()` on the same object, you have a data race, and undefined behaviour.

You can fix this by using a mutex to serialize the calls so that only one object is accessing the thread at any one time, but instead I would consider if your design makes sense. Hint: it doesn't. Calling `joinable()` will tell you if the thread has *been joined*, not if a call to `join()` has started. A thread can't be joined while it's still running (the call to `join()` will block and wait for it to finish). So the running thread can never see `joinable() == false` for the `std::thread` object that manages it, because if it's able to call `joinable()` then it's still running, and so it's joinable!

So:

1. Trying to do this risks undefined behaviour unless you're very careful.
2. It doesn't makes sense anyway.

Instead use something like a `std::atomic<bool>` (or a `bool` and a `std::mutex`) that records whether the thread has been requested to stop running, and check it from the running thread.